# angulartics piwik not working

Tags: angularjs, matomo, angulartics

I have a angularjs SPA and want to track page views with piwik. I have the following setup:

index.html:

```
<html>
  ...
  <body>
    <piwik site-id="{{settings.PiwikSiteId}}"></piwik>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//analytics.myserver.net/piwik.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/dist/common.js"></script> <!-- includes app bootstrapping and directive -->
  </body>
</html>
```

piwik directive:

```
var _paq = _paq || [];

app.directive('piwik',
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        siteId: '@'
      },
      controller: ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
        var piwikTrackingApiUrl =     'https://analytics.myserver.net/piwik.php';

        _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', piwikTrackingApiUrl]);
        _paq.push(['setSiteId', $scope.siteId]);
        _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
        _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
      }] 
    }
  });
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('ncApp', ['infinite-scroll', 'ngRoute', ..., 'angulartics', 'angulartics.piwik', ...]);
```

In the debugger I can see _paq being filled, but there is no request to https://analytics.myserver.net/piwik.php

Comment: The piwik directive is something you have created? The code shows clear that the `_paq` is filled, but not that the request is send.

Comment: yes I created the directive because we are using Content-Security-Policy, so no inline-code is allowed. The code inside the directive is the code you normally put on your site if there is no CSP.

Comment: It's normal that there is not any tracking events send, the directive does not send them ... Ignore the inital page tracking because Angular does not work page / request based... You will have to trigger the sending of the tracking event yourself...

Comment: @daan.desmedt the angulartics documentation (https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics-piwik/blob/master/README.md) says that the events are sent automatically on routechange